# Editing channel permissions using discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have got my options in a const value channel and reason and i am trying to edit the channels permission to lock the channel. Here is my current code for this command.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("lock")
    .setDescription("Locks the channel u specify.")
    .addChannelOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("channel")
        .setDescription("The channel u want to lock.")
        .setRequired(true)
    )
    .addStringOption((option) =>
      option
        .setName("reason")
        .setDescription("The reason why the channel was locked.")
        .setRequired(true)
    ),
  async execute(interaction, client) {
    const channel = interaction.options.getChannel("channel");
    let reason = interaction.options.getString("reason");

        channel.permissionOverwrites.edit(interaction.guild.roles.everyone.id, {
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true,
            ATTACH_FILES: false
        });
      await interaction.reply({
        content: `Locked channel ${channel} for the reason ${reason}`
      });
  },
};
```

But i am getting an error at line 23 where `channel.permissionOverwrites.edit` is.
ERROR:

```
C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Bobbie\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:168
    throw new RangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
          ^
    at PermissionOverwriteManager.upsert (C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Bobbie\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\PermissionOverwriteManager.js:100:50)
    at PermissionOverwriteManager.edit (C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Bobbie\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\PermissionOverwriteManager.js:145:17)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Bobbie\src\commands\moderation\lock.js:23:38)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Bobbie\src\events\client\interactionCreate.js:11:31)    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Bobbie\src\functions\handlers\handleEvents.js:21:23)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Robin\Documents\Bobbie\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:81:12) {  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to this issue. The new discord.js update v14 now uses the `PermissionsBitField.Flags`.

So the fixed code is

```js
channel.permissionOverwrites.set([
  {
    id: interaction.guild.id,
    deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.SendMessages],
  }, {
    id: interaction.guild.id,
    allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ViewChannel],
  }, {
    id: interaction.guild.id,
    allow: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.ReadMessageHistory]
  }, {
     id: interaction.guild.id,
    deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.CreatePublicThreads]
  }, {
    id: interaction.guild.id,
    deny: [PermissionsBitField.Flags.CreatePrivateThreads]
  }
]);
```